# how to calculate % of wins? javascript discord.js

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js

I want to calculate the % of wins in the following case:

games played: 12,751

wins: 6,957 (% here show percentage)

losses: 5,689.

I take example from another bot:

games played: 1.275

wins: 638  (50.04%)

losses: 595

how can I do this? anyone help

Comment: `((wins / games played) * 100) + '%'`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the formular `parts / whole * 100`. In your case its `games_won / games_played * 100 = 44.61610854050663`.

Which can then be rounded with `Math.round` or `<Number>.toFixed`.

```js
const games_played = 12751
const games_won = 5689

let resultA = (games_won / games_played * 100).toFixed(2) + "%" // '44.62%'
let resultB = Math.round(games_won / games_played * 100) + "%" // '45%'
```

Or without rounding.

```js
let resultC = games_won / games_played * 100 // 44.61610854050663
```

Comment: pedantic, but it'd be `parts / whole`.